# Unable to redirect output of "java" command to text file

Tags: java, redirect, output

I am trying the following in my cmd prompt:

java>temp.txt

temp.txt is getting created with no content in it. "java" command output is displayed in console itself without getting redirecting to temp.txt

But if i do the following:

dir> temp.txt

output of dir command is getting redirected to temp file.

Why is the output of "java" command not getting redirected to the text file??

Answer (score 12):

The `>` is for sending the `standard output` (stdout) to a given location. But the output printed with `java` command is coming in `standard error` (stderr) output.

To redirect stderr, you can use the below syntax. This will redirect `standard outputs` to `stdout.txt` and `standard errors` to `stderr.txt`

```
java > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

Alternatively you can send both `standard output` and `standard error` to same file using below command (without mentioning the filenames twice).

```
java > output.txt 2>&1
```

`2>` means redirect the stderr, `&1` means to where the stdout is redirected which is `output.txt`. So this command will redirect stdout to output.txt and stderr to where the stdout is redirected (which is output.txt iteself).

You can also ignore the `stderr` by sending it to say, `/dev/null` (only linux)

```
java > out.txt 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: what if: java   2>&1

Answer (score 1):

Because when you run `java` without arguments, the output is redirected to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. So you should do:

```
java 2>temp.txt
```

`2` tells the command to redirect `stderr` to the file `temp.txt`

More details on http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But how do you know that "java" command redirects output to stderr.

Comment: I didn't know, but I've made a test redirecting stdout and stderr to a file, and found out the answer